# CJuiAutoComplete submit selected value

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I try to get the selected value from dropdown, but it only takes the written value.
How can I take the selected value?

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete',array(
    'id'        => 'autosuggest_name',
    'name'      => 'model',
    'options'   => array('minLength'=>'1'),

    'source'    => $this->createUrl("advertisements/autocompleteBoatModels"),

    'htmlOptions'=> array(
        'maxlength' => 30
    ),
    'options'   => array(
        'delay'     => 100,
        'showAnim'  => 'fold',
        'select'    => 'js:function(event,ui){
            $("#hmodel").val(ui.item.model_id);
            $(event.target.form).submit();
        }',
    ),
));
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't work

```
$("#hmodel").val(ui.item.model_id).submit
```

Where is the error :)
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make ajax call instead of submit

```
'select'=>'js:function(event, ui) { 
           $.ajax({
           type:"POST",
           url: "/your/url",
           data: {selected:ui.item.id},
           success:function(data) {}
           });
```